# Self-inductance iteration

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Changing current in a loop of wire gives rise to a changing magnetic flux, which is responsible for an induced current on the loop itself. But the induced current should not necessarily be constant itself, so even that might create another 'induced' changing magnetic flux; revealing an 'induced-induced' current on the loop itself.  Also if we continue, we might get an 'induced-induced-induced' current and so on, with corresponding magnetic fluxes. Is this argument an exaggeration?

Comment: This is why the simultaneous solution of a system of equations is required.